# different between function above widget state and below

Tags: flutter, dart

so one of my company developer write this code and i try to understand it why he put it above not below because i usually put all my function below widget state, is there any different by putting function above or below in stateful widget ?

```
MasterAppointmentCreatePage(
    this.data, {
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final dynamic data;
  void showModal({
    double elevation = 1,
    BuildContext context,
    Widget modalContent,
    bool isDismissable = true,
  }) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        elevation: elevation,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0)),
        ),
        isScrollControlled: isDismissable,
        context: context,
        isDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              modalContent,
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: In your code there is no difference in both case either you put showModel function above or below widget state, but if you need to access widget state variables then you need to pass it in method body.